# How to group data based on continuous date range?

Tags: sql, sql-server, gaps-and-islands

I am trying to group the below sample data based on date and price.

| PRODUCT_CODE | PRICING_DATE | PRICE |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1234 | 01-01-2022 | 23.9 |
| 1234 | 02-01-2022 | 23.9 |
| 1234 | 03-01-2022 | 23.9 |
| 1234 | 04-01-2022 | 22.9 |
| 1234 | 05-01-2022 | 22.9 |
| 1234 | 06-01-2022 | 24.9 |
| 1234 | 07-01-2022 | 24.9 |
| 1234 | 08-01-2022 | 23.9 |
| 1234 | 09-01-2022 | 23.9 |

Desired Output:

| PRODUCT_CODE | MIN_DATE | MAX_DATE | PRICE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1234 | 01-01-2022 | 03-01-2022 | 23.9 |
| 1234 | 04-01-2022 | 05-01-2022 | 22.9 |
| 1234 | 06-01-2022 | 07-01-2022 | 24.9 |
| 1234 | 08-01-2022 | 09-01-2022 | 23.9 |

I have tried with this query but it doesn't give the right output.

```
SELECT Product_Code,
    min(Pricing_Date) AS Min_Date,
    max(Pricing_Date) AS Max_Date, 
    price 
FROm PRICE_DATA
GROUP BY
    Product_Code,
    Price
```

Which outputs

| PRODUCT_CODE | MIN_DATE | MAX_DATE | PRICE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1234 | 01-01-2022 | 09-01-2022 | 23.9 |
| 1234 | 04-01-2022 | 05-01-2022 | 22.9 |
| 1234 | 06-01-2022 | 07-01-2022 | 24.9 |

So the date range for price is 23.9 is not right because price not same for all the days in that range. I am not sure how to partition the data as desired output.

Basically I don't want any overlapping date ranges.

Database: SQL Server 13

Comment: Wha's your dbms?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> the date range for price is 23.9 is not right because price not same for all the days in that range.

Because there are two same `price` in different overlapping date ranges, so you might get only one row when you used aggregate function.

This is a gap-and-island problem, we can try to use `ROW_NUMBER` window function to get the gap of overlapping date and then `group by` that.

```
SELECT  Product_Code,
        min(Pricing_Date) AS Min_Date ,
        max(Pricing_Date) AS Max_Date, 
        price
FROM (
    SELECT *,
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY PRICING_DATE) - ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY  PRODUCT_CODE,PRICE ORDER  BY PRICING_DATE) grp
    FROM PRICE_DATA 
) t1
GROUP BY grp,Product_Code,price
ORDER BY  min(Pricing_Date)
```

[sqlfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019l&fiddle=a7e64d2e130a9e78dc02d4a67d08a464)

**Explain**

The gap-and-island problem is a feature

> continuous(overlapping) data is that a set `(continuous range of sequence) - (values ​​based on a certain order of conditions sequence)` yields the same grouping.

so that We can use

- `ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY PRICING_DATE)` making a continuous range of values.
- `ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY  PRODUCT_CODE,PRICE ORDER  BY PRICING_DATE)` making values ​​based on a certain order of conditions.

Then we will get a grouping column with overlapping data as [sqlfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019l&fiddle=3edaf6e06cb0d865824b793386ff2ccd)

Comment: That worked , Thanks heaps. But I dont think i understand that inner query well, can you please add some explanation on what its doing ?

Comment: @AKG I add more explain hope that help you

Comment: Hi @D-Shih, The query is working ok but sometimes bit inconsitent with the result , sometimes its creating more group even though date is continious , my actual use case data is quite big and running the same query again result in different number of rows. Any idea what might be the reason. ? is the SQL order by causing it ?